# How can I print a table in R with ascii, html, or markdown formatting?

Tags: r

```
library(xtable)
library(rattle)
set.seed(42)
obs <- sample(1:nrow(weatherAUS), 5)
vars <- 2:7
xtable(weatherAUS[obs, vars])
```

I get the following output with the code, why can't I get the formatted table?

```
% latex table generated in R 2.15.1 by xtable 1.7-1 package  
% Sat Apr  6 17:02:37 2013  
\begin{table}[ht]  
\centering  
\begin{tabular}{rlrrrrr}  
  \hline  
 & Location & MinTemp & MaxTemp & Rainfall & Evaporation & Sunshine \\   
  \hline  
60992 & Hobart & 5.60 & 13.00 & 7.60 & 1.60 & 3.10 \\   
  62476 & Launceston & 7.40 & 13.50 & 8.80 &  &  \\   
  19077 & Williamtown & 18.30 & 29.10 & 3.20 & 1.00 & 7.00 \\   
  55366 & PerthAirport & 9.80 & 21.90 & 0.00 & 3.60 & 9.80 \\   
  42784 & GoldCoast & 23.40 & 30.40 & 0.00 &  &  \\   
   \hline  
\end{tabular}  
\end{table}
```

Comment: The table appears when you're in the LaTeX environment, it doesn't format to the output. What is it that you want? A document with the table? Export a pretty table to Word/LibreOffice?

Comment: I demonstrate half a dozen methods here: http://rpubs.com/benmarwick/tables-rmarkdown

Answer (score 24, accepted):

What you get returned from `xtable` is pretty formatted, but as it is being in LaTeX syntax, it would be worth to run through a LaTeX compiler like `pdflatex`. That would return a pdf document like this:

[image: compiled pdf file]

If you want a formatted table  inside the R console, so a rather human-readable version of the standard `print.data.frame`, you might give a try to the `ascii` or my `pander` package. Examples:

1. A basic `ascii` call:

   ```
   > library(ascii)
   > ascii(weatherAUS[obs, vars])
   |=================================================================================== 
   1.1+| h| Location     h| MinTemp h| MaxTemp h| Rainfall h| Evaporation h| Sunshine 
   | 60992 | Hobart       | 5.60    | 13.00   | 7.60     | 1.60        | 3.10     
   | 62476 | Launceston   | 7.40    | 13.50   | 8.80     |             |          
   | 19077 | Williamtown  | 18.30   | 29.10   | 3.20     | 1.00        | 7.00     
   | 55366 | PerthAirport | 9.80    | 21.90   | 0.00     | 3.60        | 9.80     
   | 42784 | GoldCoast    | 23.40   | 30.40   | 0.00     |             |          
   |===================================================================================
   ```
2. Calling `ascii` to return the table in e.g. reStructuredText format:

   ```
   > print(ascii(weatherAUS[obs, vars]), type = "rest")

   +-------+--------------+---------+---------+----------+-------------+----------+
   |       | Location     | MinTemp | MaxTemp | Rainfall | Evaporation | Sunshine |
   +=======+==============+=========+=========+==========+=============+==========+
   | 60992 | Hobart       | 5.60    | 13.00   | 7.60     | 1.60        | 3.10     |
   +-------+--------------+---------+---------+----------+-------------+----------+
   | 62476 | Launceston   | 7.40    | 13.50   | 8.80     |             |          |
   +-------+--------------+---------+---------+----------+-------------+----------+
   | 19077 | Williamtown  | 18.30   | 29.10   | 3.20     | 1.00        | 7.00     |
   +-------+--------------+---------+---------+----------+-------------+----------+
   | 55366 | PerthAirport | 9.80    | 21.90   | 0.00     | 3.60        | 9.80     |
   +-------+--------------+---------+---------+----------+-------------+----------+
   | 42784 | GoldCoast    | 23.40   | 30.40   | 0.00     |             |          |
   +-------+--------------+---------+---------+----------+-------------+----------+
   ```
3. Using `pander` to return the table in different markdown formats:

   ```
   > library(pander)
   > panderOptions('table.split.table', Inf)
   > pander(weatherAUS[obs, vars])

   --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
     &nbsp;      Location    MinTemp   MaxTemp   Rainfall   Evaporation   Sunshine 
   ----------- ------------ --------- --------- ---------- ------------- ----------
    **60992**     Hobart       5.6      13.0       7.6          1.6         3.1    

    **62476**   Launceston     7.4      13.5       8.8                             

    **19077**  Williamtown    18.3      29.1       3.2          1.0         7.0    

    **55366**  PerthAirport    9.8      21.9       0.0          3.6         9.8    

    **42784**   GoldCoast     23.4      30.4       0.0                             
   --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   ```
4. Or in `grid` format:

   ```
   > pandoc.table(weatherAUS[obs, vars], style = 'grid')

   +-------------+--------------+-----------+-----------+------------+---------------+------------+
   |   &nbsp;    |   Location   |  MinTemp  |  MaxTemp  |  Rainfall  |  Evaporation  |  Sunshine  |
   +=============+==============+===========+===========+============+===============+============+
   |  **60992**  |    Hobart    |    5.6    |   13.0    |    7.6     |      1.6      |    3.1     |
   +-------------+--------------+-----------+-----------+------------+---------------+------------+
   |  **62476**  |  Launceston  |    7.4    |   13.5    |    8.8     |               |            |
   +-------------+--------------+-----------+-----------+------------+---------------+------------+
   |  **19077**  | Williamtown  |   18.3    |   29.1    |    3.2     |      1.0      |    7.0     |
   +-------------+--------------+-----------+-----------+------------+---------------+------------+
   |  **55366**  | PerthAirport |    9.8    |   21.9    |    0.0     |      3.6      |    9.8     |
   +-------------+--------------+-----------+-----------+------------+---------------+------------+
   |  **42784**  |  GoldCoast   |   23.4    |   30.4    |    0.0     |               |            |
   +-------------+--------------+-----------+-----------+------------+---------------+------------+
   ```
5. A more `simple`r format:

   ```
   > pandoc.table(weatherAUS[obs, vars], style = 'simple')

     &nbsp;      Location    MinTemp   MaxTemp   Rainfall   Evaporation   Sunshine 
   ----------- ------------ --------- --------- ---------- ------------- ----------
    **60992**     Hobart       5.6      13.0       7.6          1.6         3.1    
    **62476**   Launceston     7.4      13.5       8.8                             
    **19077**  Williamtown    18.3      29.1       3.2          1.0         7.0    
    **55366**  PerthAirport    9.8      21.9       0.0          3.6         9.8    
    **42784**   GoldCoast     23.4      30.4       0.0
   ```
6. Or in PHPMarkdown Extra/piped syntax to be used with `knitr`:

   ```
   > pandoc.table(weatherAUS[obs, vars], style = 'rmarkdown')

   |   &nbsp;    |   Location   |  MinTemp  |  MaxTemp  |  Rainfall  |  Evaporation  |  Sunshine  |
   |:-----------:|:------------:|:---------:|:---------:|:----------:|:-------------:|:----------:|
   |  **60992**  |    Hobart    |    5.6    |   13.0    |    7.6     |      1.6      |    3.1     |
   |  **62476**  |  Launceston  |    7.4    |   13.5    |    8.8     |               |            |
   |  **19077**  | Williamtown  |   18.3    |   29.1    |    3.2     |      1.0      |    7.0     |
   |  **55366**  | PerthAirport |    9.8    |   21.9    |    0.0     |      3.6      |    9.8     |
   |  **42784**  |  GoldCoast   |   23.4    |   30.4    |    0.0     |               |            |
   ```

Comment: very helpful tutorial, but `pandoc.table` (in  pander 0.3.1) won't take 'rmarkdown' as a style; it gives `Error in match.arg(style) : 'arg' should be one of “multiline”, “grid”, “simple”`

Comment: That's right, thank you, @David, I should have emphasised that `rmarkdown` syntax was introduced just recently, so it's not on CRAN yet (but it would get there in a week or so). Until then you might install `pander` from GitHub for the most recent version: http://rapporter.github.io/pander/#installation

Comment: rmarkdown works great and gives nice default displays with the recent presentation (.Rpres) feature in RStudio